# Click image 1 change to image 2 with hyperlink, with hover effect html

Tags: onclick, hover, href

i am trying to do:

1. **Hover effect** - Image 1 to Image 2
2. **Onclick** - Click on Image 1 change to Image 2 and image 2 has a hyperlink attached. So click again will direct to the link

I need a code to achieve 1 & 2 together and only 2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually both 1 and 2 worked, but you might want to consider preloading the images to eliminate loading time on mouse over .

Comment: @Segev -CJ- Shmueli Thanks. I am still confused about how to achieve the "2" I mentioned. Can you show me a sample code? Cheers.